# polling for RSS feed with casperjs not working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to match a token (string token) in the RSS feed using casperjs waitFor() but it does not seem to work. There are other ways (not using polling) to get around but I need to poll for it. Here is the code snippet:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.waitFor(function matchToken() {
        return this.evaluate(function() {
            if(!this.resourceExists(token)) {
                this.reload();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
});
```

The updates to rss url are not dynamic and hence, a refresh would be needed to check for the token. But it seems (from the access log) that I am not getting any hits (reload not working) on the rss url. Ideally, I would want to refresh the page if it doesn't see the token and then check for the token again & it should keep doing that until the waitFor times out.

I also tried using assertTextExists() instead of resourceExists() but even that did not work.

I am using PhantomJS (1.9.7) & the url is: https://secure.hyper-reach.com:488/rss/323708

The token I am looking for is --> **item/272935**. If you look at the url I have mentioned above, you will find this in a each guid tag. The reason why I am including "item/" also as a part of my token is so that it doesn't match any other numbers incorrectly.

Comment: I don't understand what the token is supposed to be. So you're opening the feed xml in CasperJS. It's only a file and it immediately loads, so what is it that you are waiting for?

Comment: The token is in the guid tag. Its something we generate with every post and it is the unique identifier.

Comment: And  I am waiting for the new post to the feed xml. Basically, its not static. With every test, the xml feed is updated and it takes a while to update it. So, I need to poll for the update and the token is how I make sure its being updated. The tests are run every hour

Comment: Got rid off the evaluate now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evaluate()` is the sandboxed page context. Anything inside of it doesn't have access to variables defined outside and `this` refers to `window` of the page and not `casper`. You don't need the `evaluate()` function here, since you don't access the page context.

---

The other thing is that `casper.resourceExists()` works on the resource meta data such as URL and request headers. It seems that you want to check the content of the resource. If you used `casper.thenOpen()` or `casper.open()` to open the RSS feed, then you can check with [`casper.getPageContent()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getpagecontent), if the text exists.

---

The actual problem with your code is that you mix synchronous and asynchronous code in a way that won't work. `waitFor()` is the wrong tool for the job, because you need to reload in the middle of its execution, but the check function is called so fast that there probably won't be a complete page load to actually test it.

You need to recursively check whether the document is changed to your liking.

```
var tokenTrials = 0,
    tokenFound = false;
function matchToken(){
    if (this.getPageContent().indexOf(token) === -1) {
        // token was not found
        tokenTrials++;
        if (tokenTrials < 50) {
            this.reload().wait(1000).then(matchToken);
        }
    } else {
        tokenFound = true;
    }
}

casper.then(matchToken).then(function(){
    test.assertTrue(tokenFound, "Token was found after " + tokenTrials + " trials");
});
```

Comment: resourceExists(token) did not work. It never enters the if condition. http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#resourceexists this clearly does say passing a String to the function should work; any idea what I am missing here ?

Comment: Or any other function I can use here ?

Comment: I don't know, because you haven't yet shown what the token might be and what it should match to. Add an example with markup into your question.

Comment: Can I call a then() recursively ?

Comment: Yes, you can nest all steps (`then*` and `wait*` functions).

Comment: I've seen your edit only now and I've updated my answer accordingly. `resourceExists()` is entirely the wrong function to use in this case.

Comment: The function matchToken, if its defined outside of a casper block, there is an error thrown "undefined is not a function evaluating ..." which I suspected.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. It should be `reload().wait` not `reload.wait`.

Comment: damn it, I should have fixed that myself. Thanks,